# hiding a "No file chosen" tooltip in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, dom

I know there are many question about it, but they don't answer properly.
After readings and looking for, I tried this:

```
<input id="ext-element-47" class="x-input-file x-input-el" type="file" accept="" style="display:none">
```

hiding the file-input and then

```
this.element.down(".x-input-file").dom.click();
```

this works on Chrome's console but in my JS code it doesn't. It doesn't click.

### Anyone knows why? and what can I do for make click?

> Notes:
>   I need to make click because the file element is not visible and so when it clicks it does not show unless I do element.click ().

Here is an example what I'm doing:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('o-file-field-input')[0].click()
```

```css
.o-file-field-input {
  display: none;
}

.o-big-btn {
  background-color: red;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-container x-unsized o-cont-option" data-componentid="ext-container-5" id="ext-container-5">
  <div class="x-inner x-align-center x-pack-center x-horizontal x-layout-box" id="ext-element-50">
    <div class="x-button x-button-plain open-field-icon o-big-btn x-layout-box-item x-flexed x-stretched" id="ext-OUI_BaseButton-1" data-componentid="ext-OUI_BaseButton-1" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;">
      <span class="x-button-icon x-shown smf smf-upload-file" id="ext-element-45"></span>
      <div class="o-button-bg"></div>
      <div class="x-unsized x-field-input x-has-height" id="ext-fileinput-1" data-componentid="ext-fileinput-1" style="height: 38px;">
        <input id="ext-element-47" class="x-input-file x-input-el o-file-field-input" type="file" accept="">
        <div class="x-field-mask x-hidden-display" id="ext-element-48"></div>
        <div class="x-clear-icon" id="ext-element-49">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See ya!

Comment: Hiding the default value of a `file` input is very different from hiding the element itself. Which one do you want to do?

Comment: I hid the entire element, so, now I want to open file panel when click it.

Comment: But you can't click a hidden element because it's, well, hidden. You'll need to wrap another element around it or similar.

Comment: My real need is to hide the "No file chosen" tooltip, but I dont find a way to do it

Comment: excuse me, the element it's visible:none. And yes, you can click it, I do it on Chrome's console and it works.

Comment: I think that it is a browser's property that could not be changed something like if you want to change the color of alert box.

Comment: @EsNoguera `visible: hidden` != `display: none`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This finally works well:

```js
var obElement = document.getElementsByClassName('input-file')[0];
//the title property overrides tooltip's description
obElement.setAttribute('title', ' ');
```

```css
.flex-style{
 display: flex;
}

.input-file{
 opacity: 0;
 margin-left: -40px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 45px;
}

.icon{
 width: 40px;
 height: 45px;
 background-color: blueviolet; 
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-style'>
<div class='icon'></div>
<input class='input-file' type='file'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I usually do: Wrap the input inside a `<label>` element, and then style the element as a button, for example:

```css
.pretty-file {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.pretty-file input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="pretty-file">
  Choose File
  <input type="file" />
</label>
```